# In an h5 file, how can I extract an array with the correct dimensions?

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, h5py

I have a h5 file containing several fields, the one I'm interested in being:

`images <HDF5 dataset "images": shape (1024, 1280, 1390), type "<u2">`

As I understand, there are 1390 images and each image is 1024x1280, and so I am interested in the image at position 0 so I do:

```
sequencePath = "./myFile.h5"
f = h5py.File(sequencePath, 'r')
image = np.asarray(f['images'][0])
```

However the image I get is an array of shape (1280, 1390) which is not what I expect, as I need a (1024, 1280) image. Is there anything I can do to get dimensions right?

Comment: Use the same sort of indexing as you would with a numpy array (you've read numpy basics, right?)  `f['images'][:,:,0]`

Comment: Really thankful for that!  I am relatively new to Python and I have to admit that I although I have used indexing in the past but it's not something I have much proficency on. Could you explain me how does that work?